# External images not loading in RDLC report: Windows Forms Application VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, rdlc

I'm working on a windows forms application, using vb.net and microsoft sql server as backend. As for the reports, I'm using microsoft's rdlc, which has been quite satisfactory for me until I was struck with this distinct problem.

So, in the report I'm using external images, which are loaded through local filepaths, passed as parameters. I retrieve these paths from the database and pass it to the report. This method worked for me for a long time, until it stopped working. Now the case is, that the external images are not loading in the report (a red cross is displayed instead of the image). As far as I feel, this problem has something to do with permissions on my PC because the same code and configurations worked for me before, but I'm not able to resolve it. I have searched everywhere to no end and would definitely want assistance.

My code for the report is:

> 

```
  Try
            With Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport
                .DataSources.Clear()
                .ReportPath = Application.StartupPath & "\RptArticle.rdlc"
                
                .EnableExternalImages = True


                Dim imagepathstring As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder & "\ArticlePics", imagepath)
                Dim imgparameter As New ReportParameter
                imgparameter = New ReportParameter("ImagePath", "file://" & imagepathstring, True)
                .SetParameters(imgparameter)


                Dim barpathstring As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder & "\BarCode", barpath)
                Dim barcode As New ReportParameter("Barcode", "file://" & barpathstring, True)
                .SetParameters(barcode)

                .DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DSArticleAccessory", Accdt))

                .DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DSArticleSize", AccSdt))

                .DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DSArticleColour", AccCdt))

                .DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DSArticleColour", AccCdt))

                .DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DSArticle", dt))



            End With

            Me.ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.PageWidth

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

When I load the report, the output is:

> Warning: Images with external URL references will not display if the report is published to a report server without an UnattendedExecutionAccount or the target image(s) are not enabled for anonymous access. (rsWarningFetchingExternalImages)
> Warning: The value of the MIMEType property for the image ‘Image1’ is “application/octet-stream”, which is not a valid MIMEType. (rsInvalidMIMEType)
> Warning: The value of the ImageData property for the image ‘Image1’ is “”, which is not a valid ImageData. (rsInvalidExternalImageProperty)
> Warning: The value of the MIMEType property for the image ‘Image2’ is “application/octet-stream”, which is not a valid MIMEType. (rsInvalidMIMEType)
> Warning: The value of the ImageData property for the image ‘Image2’ is “”, which is not a valid ImageData. (rsInvalidExternalImageProperty)
> The thread 0x3948 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using external images, you can pass your images as string to your report as parameters.

Convert your image to Base64 string first using this:

```
Public Function ImageToBase64(ByVal image As Image, ByVal format As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat) As String
   Dim base64String As String = ""
   Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
      image.Save(ms, format)
      Dim imageBytes As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
      base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes)
   End Using
   Return base64String
End Function
```

So this:

```
Dim imagepathstring As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder & "\ArticlePics", imagepath)
Dim imgparameter As New ReportParameter
imgparameter = New ReportParameter("ImagePath", "file://" & imagepathstring, True)
.SetParameters(imgparameter)


Dim barpathstring As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder & "\BarCode", barpath)
Dim barcode As New ReportParameter("Barcode", "file://" & barpathstring, True)
.SetParameters(barcode)
```

will be like this:

```
Dim imagepathstring As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder & "\ArticlePics", imagepath)
Dim imgparameter As New ReportParameter
imgparameter = New ReportParameter("ImagePath", ImageToBase64(Image.FromFile(imagepathstring),<THE IMAGE FORMAT OF YOUR IMAGE>))
.SetParameters(imgparameter)


Dim barpathstring As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder & "\BarCode", barpath)
Dim barcode As New ReportParameter("Barcode", ImageToBase64(Image.FromFile(barpathstring),<THE IMAGE FORMAT OF YOUR IMAGE>))
.SetParameters(barcode)
```

Then, in your report set the following for:

```
ImagePath

MIMEType = select the correct MIME type from the dropdown list
Source = Database
Value = <Expression>
```

and in the Expression window:

```
=System.Convert.FromBase64String(Parameters!ImagePath.Value)

Barcode

MIMEType = select the correct MIME type from the dropdown list
Source = Database
Value = <Expression>

=System.Convert.FromBase64String(Parameters!Barcode.Value)
```